# Write a file where the deployed .exe file is executed

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a console application written in C#, and i want to write the output of my execution in a log file.

In my code actually i use this path : `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

It's working fine when i run with debug command in Visual Studio and my logfile is created and works well.

But when i publish my application, the path is not the local path where the .exe is executed but in my AppData folder ...

I tried many other syntax and all of them works in debug mode but not when i deploy my application.

I want to get the local path, where my .exe is executed to write a logfile here. Thanks.

I deploy it with Visual Studio, simply publish option. 
I get a setup.exe and a .application file

Regards,

Comment: have you looked at `Environment.CurrentDirectory`?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 That won't necessarily provide the path to the folder containing the executable. For example, if your application was started from a shortcut, it would be whatever the working directory set in the shortcut was.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 Yep, not working after deploy

Comment: How do you deploy it?

Comment: I deploy it with Visual Studio, simply publish option. I get a setup.exe and a .application file. Added this comment to my answer

Comment: Are you using ClickOnce to deploy your application? If so, I think the folder in AppData might actually be where it is running from. Question: how are you executing your application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You in general can never hope to write a file in the same directory as your installed exe.  Works when you debug it but not after you deploy it.  Programs do not have write access to the C:\Program Files directories.  How it ended up in AppData is a bit hard to guess, you would have to intentionally remove the manifest from the program so the OS treats you like a legacy XP program that is not UAC aware.  Hmm.

Well, never go there, just use Environment.GetFolderPath() to obtain an AppData path, have your installer create that directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can try getting the Entry Assembly instead (which in your case should be the executable you ran).

```
var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
var file = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(entryAssembly.Location), 
    entryAssembly.GetName().Name + ".log"),
```